# print function in while loop not printing

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, printing, record

I'm new to python and i have several questionable things that are happening. I am trying to figure out what i'm doing wrong with this problem:

This exercise assumes you have completed Programming Exercise 7, Random Number File
Writer. Write another program that reads the random numbers from the file, display the
numbers, and then display the following data:
• The total of the numbers
• The number of random numbers read from the file

Writing the file:

```
import random

def main():

    randomcount = int(input('How many numbers should i generate?'))

    randomfile = open('randomnumber.txt', 'w')

    total = 0
    for numbers in range(randomcount):
        number = random.randint(1,100)
        total+= number
        randomfile.write((str(number)) + '\n')
        randomfile.write((str(total)) + '\n') 

    randomfile.close()
    print('File updated')

main()
```

output:

```
How many numbers should i generate?5 (enter)
file updated                    -       **Question 1**
file updated                     | ---- this is new.. while doing 
file updated                    -       trial and error this started
                                        repeating. First 2 times then 
                                        after awhile 3 times. 
                                        Refreshed kernel and outputs 
                                        still does this
```

reading the file:   <-- #**main issue**

```
def main():
    randomfile = open('randomnumber.txt','r')

    contents = randomfile.readline()

    while randomfile !='':
        total = randomfile.readline()

        contents = contents.rstrip('\n')
        total = total.rstrip('\n')

        print(contents)

        contents = randomfile.readline()

   print('total: ',total)
   randomfile.close()

main()
```

output:

```
90                      -
22                       |
17                       |--- Randomly generated
2                        |
75                      -
        **Question 2**
        <--- print('total: ', total) not showing up


        -
         |
         |
         |
         .   **Question 3**
         .   <--------- Space goes on forever like if its printing 
         .              space. so much that theres a scroll bar just
         .              for empty space. if i try to scroll all the 
         |              way to the bottom so that i can see if maybe 
         |              its printing at the end i never reach the end 
         |              of it because for some reason the program 
        -               keeps adding more and more space.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the line that writes the total is being execute each iteration. That's why there are double the number of lines as there are generated numbers.

The solution is unindenting that line, which I did here:

```py
import random

def main():

    randomcount = int(input('How many numbers should i generate?'))

    randomfile = open('randomnumber.txt', 'w')

    total = 0
    for numbers in range(randomcount):
        number = random.randint(1,100)
        total+= number
        randomfile.write((str(number)) + '\n')
    randomfile.write((str(total)) + '\n') # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<This line was indented, it is fixed now.

    randomfile.close()
    print('File updated')

main()
```

EDIT: Fixing the read function:

```py
def main():
    randomfile = open('randomnumber.txt', 'r')
    lines = randomfile.readlines()
    total = 0

    for line in lines:
        if line is lines[-1]:
            print(f"Total: {line.replace('\n', '')}") #Since the write function includes the total as the last line, you don't need to calculate here.
        else:
            print(line.replace('\n', ''))

main()
```

Comment: used your advise however now the reading portion is flagging an error  at   contents = contents.rstrip('\n')  'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Comment: That isn't an error with the code I posted, maybe try copy+paste what I posted?

EDIT: What python version are you using?

Comment: The portion you edited works but if you look above to my attached code i have a block for reading ( 3rd gray box). Thats where i'm having the issue currently.

Comment: Thanks for providing another way to answer it. I also figured out that a for loop would work best. I attached an answer that works above that looks  similar to yours except i  havent learned some of the stuff you used to solve it like f strings.

Answer (score 0):

change `readline` to `readlines` hopefully, that should work

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the issue is that in your first line you opened with a single quote `'` and closed with a double quote `"`. Change:

```
def main():

    randomcount = int(input('How many numbers should i generate?"))
```

to:

```
def main():

    randomcount = int(input('How many numbers should i generate?'))
```

Comment: If that was the problem he would be getting an error

Comment: That was just a typo transferring it to stack overflow. Not the main issue. corrected the typo Thank you for responding though

Answer (score 0):

I restructured my code and made it a for loop instead of a while loop. You don't need to rstrip numbers that are being converted to int. Put the accumulator in the input file portion instead of the output file portion. Mae the code cleaner and it works!

import random

```
def main():

    randomcount = int(input('How many numbers should i generate?'))

    randomfile = open('randomnumber.txt', 'w')

    for numbers in range(1,randomcount + 1):
        numbers = random.randint(1,100)

        randomfile.write(str(numbers) + '\n') 

    randomfile.close()

    randomfile = open('randomnumber.txt','r')
    total = 0

    for numbers in randomfile:
        numbers = int(numbers)
        total+= numbers

        print(numbers)
    print('total',total)

main()
```